# Linux: delete files that don't contain specific number of lines

Tags: linux

How to remove files inside a directory that have more or less lines than specified (all files have ".txt" suffix)?

Comment: belongs on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Why should it? Linux is not only used on servers...

Comment: Serverfault is not just for servers. It's for *admin questions*. Even though a developer might need to do this, it's better suited for that community, IMHO.

Answer (score 11):

This bash script should do the trick. Save as "rmlc.sh".

Sample usage:

```
rmlc.sh -more 20 *.txt   # Remove all .txt files with more than 20 lines
rmlc.sh -less 15 *       # Remove ALL files with fewer than 15 lines
```

Note that if the rmlc.sh script is in the current directory, it is protected against deletion.

---

```
#!/bin/sh

# rmlc.sh - Remove by line count

SCRIPTNAME="rmlc.sh"
IFS=""

# Parse arguments 
if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "$SCRIPTNAME [-more|-less] [numlines] file1 file2..."
    exit 
fi

if [ $1 == "-more" ]; then
    COMPARE="-gt" 
elif [ $1 == "-less" ]; then
    COMPARE="-lt" 
else
    echo "First argument must be -more or -less"
    exit 
fi

LINECOUNT=$2

# Discard non-filename arguments
shift 2

for filename in $*; do
    # Make sure we're dealing with a regular file first
    if [ ! -f "$filename" ]; then
        echo "Ignoring $filename"
        continue
    fi

    # We probably don't want to delete ourselves if script is in current dir
    if [ "$filename" == "$SCRIPTNAME" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Feed wc with stdin so that output doesn't include filename
    lines=`cat "$filename" | wc -l`

    # Check criteria and delete
    if [ $lines $COMPARE $LINECOUNT ]; then
        echo "Deleting $filename"
        rm "$filename"
    fi 
done
```

Comment: My only issue with this is the "gratuitous use of cat". wc -l can operate on a file all by itself: wc -l "$filename" is all you need.

Comment: Harper: I originally tried "wc -l" by itself. The problem is that the output includes the filename rather than just the line number. For example, "wc -l rmlc.sh" outputs "48 rmlc.sh", while "echo rmlc.sh | wc -l" simply outputs "48".

Comment: this will fail on filenames containing spaces, and iirc on large directories.  See my "find" based comment for one way around that.

Comment: Kevin's script works great, so does Simon's solution. No flaws, even though I deal with more than 4 000 files. If I could I would accept both :)
Thank you all for your answers, I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: `wc -l < "$filename"`, kill the cat

Answer (score 4):

Played a bit with the answer from 0x6adb015. This works for me:

```
LINES=10
for f in *.txt; do
  a=`cat "$f" | wc -l`;
  if [ "$a" -ne "$LINES" ]
  then
    rm -f "$f"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Switched to "cat" the file, too.

Answer (score 3):

This one liner should also do

```
 find -name '*.txt' | xargs  wc -l | awk '{if($1 > 1000 && index($2, "txt")>0 ) print $2}' | xargs rm
```

In the example above, files greater than 1000 lines are deleted.

Choose > and < and the number of lines accordingly.

Comment: Use xargs -0 if filenames can contain space.

Answer (score 1):

Try this bash script:

```
LINES=10
for f in *.txt; do 
  if [ `cat "$f" | wc -l` -ne $LINES ]; then 
     rm -f "$f"
  fi
done
```

(Not tested)

**EDIT:** Use a pipe to feed in wc, as wc prints the filename as well.

Comment: I also tried to do this: a=`wc -l "$f`; if [ "$a" -ne $LINES ]; This would work, but wc -l does output the count and the filename...

Comment: Arg! do [ `cat "$f" | wc -l` -ne $LINES ];

Answer (score 1):

My command line mashing is pretty rusty, but I think something like this will work safely (change the "10" to whatever number of lines in the grep) even if your filenames have spaces in them.  Adjust as needed.  You'd need to tweak it if newlines in filenames are possible.

```
find . -name \*.txt -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | grep -v "^10 .*$" | cut --complement -f 1 -d " " | tr '\012' '\000' | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Comment: Thank you Simon, both your command line and Kevin's script work perfectly, even though I have more than 4 000 files :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner option. `RLINES` is the number of lines to use for removal.

```
rm \`find $DIR -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | grep "^$RLINES " | awk '{print $2}'\`
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late since the question was asked. I just had the same question, and this is what a came up with, in the lines of [Chad Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33787463/2486809)

```
find $DIR -name '*.txt' -exec wc -l {} \; | grep -v "$LINES" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm
```

- First part looks for all the files in DIR ending in *.txt and print
  the number of lines.
- Second part select all the files that **do not** have the required
  number of lines (LINES).
- The third part prints just the file names.
- And the forth part deletes those files.