# Getting everything between two characters

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'd like to search for two consecutive * characters and save everything between them including the first line with *.
Example:
 input:

```
A*1
A
B
B*4
C
Y*5
D
```

output 1:

```
A*1
A
B
```

output 2:

```
B*4
C
```

output 3:

```
Y*5
D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk '/\*/ { n++; } { print >> "output" n }' inputfile
```

This writes three files, `output1`, `output2` and `output3` with the contents in your question. Any text before a line containing a `*` would go into `output`.

Comment: Thanks! how can I define a condition on the number of printing lines. e.g print each output if the number of lines are >3.

Comment: @ahb65 are you saying you don't want output2 and output3 in your example because they're less than 3 lines?

Comment: @ahb65 [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935251/linux-delete-files-that-dont-contain-specific-number-of-lines) has some suggestions for deleting files based on their number of lines

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="your delimiter"} {print $0}'
```

RS is the Records Separator, defining it at the beginning will let you split the input however you want.

Use NR to print the current record number

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="\""} {print "output " NR ":\n" $0}'
```

Comment: Thanks! how can I define a condition on the number of printing lines. e.g print on each output if the number of lines are >3.

Comment: awk 'BEGIN { RS="\""} NR > 3 {print "output " NR ":\n" $0}'

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
csplit -zf 'output' file '/\*/' '{*}'
```

This splits the file on `*`'s (`/\*/`) and names the result files `outputnn` where `nn` starts at 00. Files with empty lines are not output and the process is repeated to the end of file ( `{*}`).